# Predicate for selecting item with subset of relation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate

I have a DB with a list of days ('Day' objects).
Each day has a list of events (one-to-many)

How do I write a fetch predicate in order to fetch all day objects where name=='Monday' and only include the events where the time is > aStartTime and time < aEndTime?

Or in other words....

I want an array of 'Monday' objects where day.events only contains the events for a certain time interval.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have "Day" objects? What you actually seem to want is a collection of event objects that is filtered by a date/day.

Comment: The actual object info is not relevant - its just for the sample here. What I want tis to be able to get a list of objects and a subset of their relations

Answer (score 0):

You can't without adding new Day objects; it goes against the whole point of Core Data (object graph/change management). And if each event can only have one Day, it gets messy.

Alternatively, you can return some sort of "proxy" Day objects, but that won't quite do the same thing (it might be closer to what you're looking for, though).

Alternatively, in each event, store a number between 0 and 60*60*24*7, do the query, and sort the results however you like.

Alternatively, tell us what you're actually trying to achieve and we might be able to give a better answer.